# Cancellation of Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2-enterprise

Does anyone have experience with **cancellation of Magento Enterprise**? I notified them of our plan to **cancel** the service about **15 days prior to our renewal** date instead of more than **30 days in advance**. Magento is now demanding that we still pay for the full year, even though we have been completely off the platform...

**Is this normal?** I will also add that our renewal manager did NOT mention this **cancellation policy** in any emails, until we were outside of the policy. As soon as it was mentioned, I responded. Though they assure this wasnt done purposefully, I couldn't help but feel that it should be mandatory to recount this fine detail of your contract in renewal reminder emails. It feels like a predatory cancellation policy IMO and I would've expected better from an Adobe backed company.

Comment: This might actually be a better question for https://law.stackexchange.com/ because I don't see how they can make you pay for something you're not using.

Comment: `did NOT mention this cancellation policy` did you ask?